# How to Delete a specific Row and Col in a dynamic 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I've created following 2D array in C++:

```
template <typename T> class Array2D {
private:
  T **items;
  int m,n;
public:
  Array2D(int m, int n, T initValue = 0) {

    this->m = m;
    this->n = n;
    this->items = new T*[m];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      this->items[i] = new T[n];
      memset(this->items[i], initValue, sizeof(T) * n);
    }
  }
...
}
```

What i want to do is to remove row / column at given index.

With row I was thinking about swapping row of interest with the following one, till I reach last row, then remove last row:

```
while (removeIndex < m - 1) {
  swap(removeIndex, removeIndex + 1);
  removeIndex++;
}
delete [] items[m];
m--;
```

But what how I can remove the column?

Comment: If you are not looking for performance you could do: you apply a transpose function to your array then apply your fuction then once again tranpose, otherwise it would be a little bit more complicated